# why fdisk doesn't show free space and cfdisk does?

Tags: fdisk

root@mik-Aspire-E5-571:~# lsb_release -a|grep Ubuntu
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 15.04
root@mik-Aspire-E5-571:~#

root@mik-Aspire-E5-571:~# fdisk -l /dev/sda

Disk /dev/sda: 465,8 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: B7CDD85F-E22A-4C24-8CDE-FDC7A88050C0

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1       2048   1230847   1228800   600M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1230848   1845247    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1845248   2107391    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    2107392 459907071 457799680 218,3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda5  634427392 907864891 273437500 130,4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  941627392 976773119  35145728  16,8G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  907866112 923490303  15624192   7,5G Linux swap
```

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

root@mik-Aspire-E5-571:~#

root@mik-Aspire-E5-571:~# cfdisk

```
Device         Start       End   Sectors   Size Type                        
 /dev/sda1       2048   1230847   1228800   600M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2    1230848   1845247    614400   300M EFI System
/dev/sda3    1845248   2107391    262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda4    2107392 459907071 457799680 218,3G Microsoft basic data
Free space 459907072 634427391 174520320  83,2G
/dev/sda5  634427392 907864891 273437500 130,4G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda6  941627392 976773119  35145728  16,8G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  907866112 923490303  15624192   7,5G Linux swap
Free space 923490304 941627391  18137088   8,7G
```

Comment: To be clear, the tools you are using are partition viewers/editors. That said, you can invoke fdisk in interactive mode with, for example: `sudo fdisk /dev/sda1` and then press 'v' to display unallocated sectors.

Answer (score 0):

Because `fdisk` is not `cfdisk`.

`cfdisk` is a Linux partition editor, **similar** to `fdisk`, but with a different user interface (curses).